# programmatically add child products of bundle product in Quote

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I am trying to create order programmatically. it is working fine with simple product but when i am trying with bundle product it will not add child product.

below is the code for that

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

$newProd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sku);

$option= array(
        "bundle_option" => array(
        "35" => 66, 
        "36" => 67
        ),
        'qty' => 1
    );

$quote->addProduct($newProd, new Varien_Object($option));
```

please any one have solution for that or where am i wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the Bundle-options array because in Bundled item there are various input type such as radio (which takes one input) checkbox (takes multiple product) similarly there are drop down as well as multiple select.

```
[bundle_option] => Array
    (
        [5] => 13
        [6] => Array
            (
                [0] => 23
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [0] => 37
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [0] => 56
            )

    )

[bundle_option_qty] => Array
    (
        [5] => 1
        [6] => Array
            (
                [23] => 1
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [37] => 1
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [56] => 1
            )

    )
```

Here is an bundle product option where [5] is an radio button and will have one product ,[6],[8] is checkox and can have more product in it and so on.

Similarly you have to maintain the product quantity as shown above.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: thanks for  the reply... but its not working for me..i have bundle product with 2 children product...and both have radio buttons and both   are required